# Flutter routing stutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to move my project from Java/Android studio to flutter but I have a stutter/lag issue when I try to change "Activity"...

As soon as I press the "Sign Up" button I want to transition to the sign up screen but when I do there is a stutter and the animation starts from the middle of the screen. The same is when I navigate back with the back button.

I started learning flutter yesterday so if you have any tips with how I can improve my layout that would also be a lot of help! :)

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/SignUp": (BuildContext context) => new SignUp()
      },
        home: new Scaffold(
          body: new WelcomePage(),
        )
    );
  }
}

class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
        return new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                      child: new Container(
                        height: 60.0,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: _SignIn,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: const Text('Sign In'),
                          textColor: Colors.white,

                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  new Expanded(
                      child: new Container(
                        height: 60.0,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/SignUp");},
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: const Text('Sign Up'),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                      child: new Container(
                        height: 60.0,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: _GoogleSignIn,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: const Text('Google Sign In'),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
  }

  void _signUp(BuildContext context){

  }

  void _signIn(){

  }

  void _googleSignIn(){

  }

}


class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("SignUp"),),
      body: new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    child: new TextField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Email",
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,

                    )
                  )
                )
              ],
            ),
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                        child: new TextField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Password",
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                        )
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're running into https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13736 ?

Comment: Is this with `--release` on a real device?

Comment: Yes it's with --release and on a Oneplus 3, which should not be the issue, because the animation starts from 1/2 of the screen.

Comment: There are similar complaints here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15116

Comment: Have opened a Github issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15294

Comment: I can reproduce the same behaviour on a Nexus 6P, Oneplus 5 and Xiaomi A1. I feel like i cannot release an app with this animation stuttering.

Comment: All of the mentioned issues have been closed off sometime in late 2018, and I'm not able to reproduce a stutter anymore. So there should be no more issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your sample code and It is working fine now.

[image]

I've traced the reported bugs in GitHub and it seems that the issue's were closed.

Also, I've found this topic on YouTube interesting, [Flutter Europe: Optimizing your Flutter App](https://youtube.com/watch?v=vVg9It7cOfY) whenever you've encountered performance issues in your Flutter app.